# 90s comic about a grim fantasy world with flaming swords

Tags: story-identification, comics

This comic is set in a grim fantasy world and it's about two dudes that have flaming swords.
They're sparring and suddenly one notices that he is on fire, running around screaming to the other one that they agreed to put out their swords during training.

After putting out the fire in a watering tub for horses, they realize they are hungry and decide to go steal chickens from a coop (these guys are anti-heroes). During the caper, a few (five, I think) very scary knights, way larger than them, break the coop to catch the main characters and encircle them on horses. These knights are very unique and not conventional in any way, but still looked like knights with dark and huge colorful armor and helmets.

They capture the thieves and lock them in cages. One of the main guys has a black flaming sword. As the captain of the knights, an orc-like giant inspects the black sword, giving the remark “nice toothpick” (“Frumoasa scobitoare” in Romanian), as it is pretty useless for him given his size.

The owner of the sword takes offense and assumes a yoga position, makes the sword teleport and breaks the lock to the suspended jail cage he and his buddy are kept. And that's all I remember.

I read it definitely during 1995-2005, somewhere in Eastern Europe, if that helps. It was in Romanian, but likely translated. It was from the 1990s.

I remember it vividly but none of the keywords I came up with had any results so it's been driving me up the wall for some time.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Hello! What language was it in? Great memory, BTW :)

Comment: Hey, it was in romanian but most likely translated from something foreign. Thank you for the edit btw. I'm ashamed to admit I wasn't aware fully of the rules of this stackexchange before I posted the question.

Comment: @IcyDinosaurs Do you maybe know what publisher it was published by?

Comment: @Stormblessed no man, sorry, I was maybe 10 years old then. This is the only thing I can remember but I'm 100% sure of it. It might be a subcomic of Pif Gadged, it was really popular in my area but that's just a wild stab in the dark on my part.

Comment: @IcyDinosaurs how do you say “nice toothpick” in Romanian?

Comment: @Stormblessed 'Frumoasa scobitoare' , and it was written exactly like that minus some punctuation I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a French comic called *Chroniques de la Lune Noire*. The scene I described in my question is right in the first volume! (I might have over exaggerated the size of the knights, they're just a bit larger).

The character I remember is called Haazeel Thorn and you can find him by searching 'Arcanes de la Lune Noire (Les) Tome 2, Pile ou face', he's the guy on the cover and the black sword is the one that teleports.

I found it with the help of TV Tropes by searching for flaming sword and going to the comic book section and in the last entry the series is mentioned. Mentioning this because maybe someone can use the same tactic for themselves.